# How to change an element style in jQuery using .data()

Tags: jquery, css

I have the follow markup:

`<button class="clickIt" data-reference="abc" style="display:inline" type="button">Content</button>`

How can I use jQuery and the `.data()` method to selectively change the style based on element's data value?

I tried the following and it does not work:

```
$( '.clickIt' ).click(function(){
  $(this).data('reference','abc').css('display','none');
});
```

I want to hide the button when clicked comparing `.data()` value.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking.  Data attributes have nothing to do with element styling.  Are you trying to hide elements that have a data attribute matching a value?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Taplar. I am trying to hide the button with a certain data-reference upon click event

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a conditional since you are operating upon a single element.

```
$( '.clickIt' ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).data('reference') === 'abc') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the data as part of your selector, like so:

```
$( ".clickIt[data-reference='abc']" ).click(function(){
  $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

Or do comparison with data field, like so:

```
$( '.clickIt' ).click(function(){
    if ($(this).data('reference') == 'abc') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Your use of `.data( 'name', 'value')` is SETTING the data, not retrieving for comparison or selecting based on value.